# Netbeans PHP Go To Declaration fails for single word functions

Tags: php, netbeans-8

Netbeans "Go To Declaration" (`Ctrl+B`) works fine for functions like "`actionEntity`" but not for functions like "`action`". As an example, if I am calling a function as below.

```
$this->members->addMember($id);
```

The "Go To Declaration" (`Ctrl+B`) works fine and goes to the function addMember of class Members in Members.php.

However if I name the `addMember` function simply as `add` in the class Members and call that as below, Netbeans is not able to "Go to Declaration".

```
$this->members->add($id);
```

Can somebody explain why it doesn't work and provide me a fix / workaround?
Thanks in anticipation.